# pack() in php. Illegal hex digit warning

Tags: php, hex, pack

i am having some problems using pack() in php

```
$currencypair = "EUR/USD";
$buy_sell = "buy";
$alert_device_token =array("a","a","b");
$message = "Your " . $currencypair . " " . $buy_sell . " alert price has been reached!";
$payload['aps'] = array (
  'alert' => $message,
  'badge' => 1,
  'sound' => 'default'
);
$payload = json_encode($payload);

foreach ($alert_device_token as $alert_device)
{
  $apnsMessage = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . 
                 pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $alert_device)) . 
                 chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;
  echo $apnsMessage;
}
```

Now sometimes i get following warnings running the same code -

```
Warning: pack() [function.pack]: Type H: illegal hex digit g in /code/FR2BVl
```

the illegal hex digit keeps varying though. Any ideas about this warning and ways to remove it.

check it live [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/FR2BVl)

Comment: Post more code. The `str_replace()` on `$alert_device` makes me think that there is more code in the middle that could be modifying the contents of `$alert_device`. With the code as posted, you shouldn't get the error that you are getting.

Comment: In my case, I received this error when I was trying to pass an empty value (or a slash /) to the pack() function. I found out what was causing the empty value and fixed that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`pack` converts hexadecimal number to binary, e.g.:

```
  echo pack("H*", "2133")
```

produces `!3`, since `!` has code 0x21 and `3` has code 0x33. Since `g` is not hex digit, warning is given. To be useful for pack's `H` format, the argument must be hex number. If `$alert_device` isn't - you should use something else, depending on what it is and what you expect as the result.

Answer (score 6):

One of the reason for the error is related to the checksums,

> Because PHP's integer type is signed many crc32 checksums will result
>   in negative integers on 32bit platforms. On 64bit installations all
>   crc32() results will be positive integers though. So you need to use
>   the "%u" formatter of sprintf() or printf() to get the string
>   representation of the unsigned crc32() checksum in decimal format. 
>   http://www.php.net/crc32

To fix the error this might be sufficient,

```
sprintf('%u', CRC32($someString))
```

In this case,

```
pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', sprintf('%u', CRC32($alert_device))))
```

Ref: https://github.com/bearsunday/BEAR.Package/issues/136

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue when developing a hybrid app using Ionic/Cordova/PhoneGap. As the same code is run in Android and iOS devices, I had made a mistake of storing Google FCM token as APNS token. The APNS token is purely hexadecimal but Google FCM token can have non-hexadecimal characters. So, packing a Google FCM token using PHP's `pack()` function will result in the `illegal hex digit` error.

Comment: Thanks! If you want APN-token instead of FCM-token for iOS don't include`GoogleService-Info.plist` in the root directory, That was my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Use `strtr(rtrim(base64_encode(pack('H*', sprintf('%u', $algo($data)))), '='), '+/', '-_')`  insted of using `pack('H*', $value)`.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, `$alert_device` is an array.

For packing it needs a value.

Use
`pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $alert_device[0]))` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You must change

```
pack('H*', $someString)
```

To

```
strtr(rtrim(base64_encode(pack('H*', sprintf('%u', CRC32($someString))))
```

Comment: Please can you add some explaining ?

Answer (score -3):

Try to save your file in utf-8 encoding.